# Sum an specific field from all elements mongoose

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collections in mongoose that store each order line, with price, product name, quantity, and total price from multiplying price with quantity,
, what I am trying TO achieve is insert in ejs the total amount of the order with the sum of total price from each element or line, basically sum all elements total field and inserted in ejs.

I took a look to the mongoose and mongodb documentation I found the $sum element but it did not answer my question.

```
 WE CAN SEE THE ELEMENT.

{ _id: 5d58512fe1ec313138b426d5,
  amount: 12,
  name: 'Bisagras de 3/8',
  price: 2.15,
  total: 25.799999999999997 }

 BELOW IS THE GET REQUEST IN NODE JS

 app.get("/order", function(req, res) {

    Order.find({}, function(err, data) {
       res.render("order", {ordenItem: data});  
    });
 });

AND THIS IS THE EJS PAGE

<% ordenItem.forEach(function(item){ %>

    <form action="/delete"  method="post" class="order">
        <div class="item">
            <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value=" 
            <%= item._id %>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
            <h3><%=   item.amount  %> <%= item.name %> <%=  item.price %> 
            </h3>
        </div>

     <h3 class="price"><%= item.total++  %></h3>
   </form>
```

Comment: When you say  "total amount of the order with the sum of total price" do you mean "total amount of orders" ?? Also do you just need count of totalAmount or some data to be retrieved along with that ? Please check my answer below !!

Comment: @srinivasy Well what I´m trying to do is take all total within the elements and sum them up so they can give a total amount.

Comment: Did you try the below query ?

Comment: Yes I tried it.

Comment: : elements are nothing but order lines? Do you need changes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this, to get the total amount for orders, this does sum up total across all the lines :

```
Order.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: '',
        totalAmount: { $sum: '$total' }
    }
 }, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0
    }
})
```